# SQL Errors on Database Insert

Tags: php, sql

I am getting an SQL syntax Error but can't seem to find the source as the code seems correct (to me).

The Error:

> Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 'test' , date = '2012-12-05' , trunk = '' , introduction = '' , title_gallery ' at line 3

The Code:

```
<?php include("../inc/approve-admin.php"); ?>
<?php include("../inc/connect.php"); ?>

<?php include('class.upload.php'); ?>

<?php
$filePath = "../images";
$dir_dest = $filePath;
$dir_pics = (isset($_GET['pics']) ? $_GET['pics'] : $dir_dest);
?>


<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<?php
$PageTitle = "Fashion Franchise Admin | Add Record";
$description = "Fashion Franchise";
$keywords = "Fashion Franchise";
$body = "home";
require "../inc/header.php";
?>


<script src="../js/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- for styling the form -->
<script src="../js/cmxforms.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addResource").validate();
});
</script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas",
        editor_deselector : "mceNoEditor"

});
</script>



    <body id="<?php echo htmlentities("$body") ?>">

    <div class="container_12">
    <!-- Nav -->
    <?php include("../inc/nav-admin.php"); ?>
    <!-- / Nav -->

    <div class="grid_12">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="grid_12">&nbsp;</div>

    <!-- Adimn List -->
    <?php include("../inc/admin-list.php"); ?>
    <!-- / Adimn List -->

    <div class="grid_7" id="white" style="min-height:400px">


        <p style="text-align:center;padding-top:20px;">
<?

    if(isset($_POST['title'])) {
        if(isset($_POST['gallery_1'])) {
            $gallery_1_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gallery_1']);
        }
        if(isset($_POST['gallery_2'])) {
            $gallery_2_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gallery_2']);
        }
            if(isset($_POST['gallery_3'])) {
            $gallery_3_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gallery_3']);
        }
            if(isset($_POST['gallery_4'])) {
            $gallery_4_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gallery_4']);
        }
            if(isset($_POST['gallery_5'])) {
            $gallery_5_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gallery_5']);
        }

            if(isset($_POST['download_1'])) {
            $download_1_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['download_1']);
        }

            if(isset($_POST['download_2'])) {
            $download_2_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['download_2']);
        }

            if(isset($_POST['download_3'])) {
            $download_3_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['download_3']);
        }

        $title_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
        $title_gallery_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title_gallery']);
        $date_to_insert = stripslashes($_POST['date']);
        $trunk_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['trunk']);
        $introduction_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['introduction']);
        $download_1_title_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['download_1_title']);
        $download_2_title_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['download_2_title']);
        $download_3_title_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['download_3_title']);
        $dropbox_title_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dropbox_title']);
        $dropbox_info_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dropbox_info']);
        $dropbox_link_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dropbox_link']);
        $video_title_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['video_title']);
        $video_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['video']);
        $id = (int)$id;   // Cast this as an integer to also make it safe


        $handle = new Upload($_FILES['gallery_1']);
            if ($handle->uploaded) {
                $handle->file_max_size = 4000000;
                $handle->image_resize = true;
                $handle->image_ratio = true;
                $handle->image_ratio_crop = true;
                $handle->image_y = 407;
                $handle->image_x = 460;
                $handle->allowed = array('image/pjpeg','image/jpeg', 'image/jpg');
                $handle->Process($dir_dest);
                if ($handle->processed) {
                    echo 'issue image 1 uploaded ' . round(filesize($handle->file_dst_pathname)/256)/4 . 'KB<br /><br />';
                    $gallery_1 = $dir_pics.'/' . $handle->file_dst_name ;
                } else {
                    echo '  the following error occurred while uploading image 1<br />';
                    echo '  Error: ' . $handle->error . '<br /><br />';
                }
                $handle-> Clean();
            }



            $handle2 = new Upload($_FILES['gallery_2']);
            if ($handle2->uploaded) {
                $handle2->file_max_size = 4000000;
                $handle2->image_resize = true;
                $handle2->image_ratio = true;
                $handle2->image_ratio_crop = true;
                $handle2->image_y = 307;
                $handle2->image_x = 460;
                $handle2->allowed = array('image/pjpeg','image/jpeg', 'image/jpg');
                $handle2->Process($dir_dest);
                if ($handle2->processed) {
                    echo 'issue image 2 uploaded ' . round(filesize($handle2->file_dst_pathname)/256)/4 . 'KB<br /><br />';
                    $gallery_2 = $dir_pics.'/' . $handle2->file_dst_name ;
                } else {
                    echo '  the following error occurred while uploading image 2<br />';
                    echo '  Error: ' . $handle2->error . '<br /><br />';
                }
                $handle2-> Clean();
            }

            $handle3 = new Upload($_FILES['gallery_3']);
            if ($handle3->uploaded) {
                $handle3->file_max_size = 4000000;
                $handle3->image_resize = true;
                $handle3->image_ratio = true;
                $handle3->image_ratio_crop = true;
                $handle3->image_y = 307;
                $handle3->image_x = 460;
                $handle3->allowed = array('image/pjpeg','image/jpeg', 'image/jpg');
                $handle3->Process($dir_dest);
                if ($handle3->processed) {
                    echo 'issue image 3 uploaded ' . round(filesize($handle3->file_dst_pathname)/256)/4 . 'KB<br /><br />';
                    $gallery_3 = $dir_pics.'/' . $handle3->file_dst_name ;
                } else {
                    echo '  the following error occurred while uploading image 3<br />';
                    echo '  Error: ' . $handle3->error . '<br /><br />';
                }
                $handle3-> Clean();
            }

            $handle4 = new Upload($_FILES['gallery_4']);
            if ($handle4->uploaded) {
                $handle4->file_max_size = 4000000;
                $handle4->image_resize = true;
                $handle4->image_ratio = true;
                $handle4->image_ratio_crop = true;
                $handle4->image_y = 307;
                $handle4->image_x = 460;
                $handle4->allowed = array('image/pjpeg','image/jpeg', 'image/jpg');
                $handle4->Process($dir_dest);
                if ($handle4->processed) {
                    echo 'main image for issue uploaded ' . round(filesize($handle4->file_dst_pathname)/256)/4 . 'KB<br /><br />';
                    $gallery_4 = $dir_pics.'/' . $handle4->file_dst_name ;
                } else {
                    echo '  the following error occurred while uploading the main image<br />';
                    echo '  Error: ' . $handle4->error . '<br /><br />';
                }
                $handle4-> Clean();
            }

            $handle5 = new Upload($_FILES['gallery_5']);
            if ($handle5->uploaded) {
                $handle5->file_max_size = 4000000;
                $handle5->image_resize = true;
                $handle5->image_ratio = true;
                $handle5->image_ratio_crop = true;
                $handle5->image_y = 307;
                $handle5->image_x = 460;
                $handle5->allowed = array('image/pjpeg','image/jpeg', 'image/jpg');
                $handle5->Process($dir_dest);
                if ($handle5->processed) {
                    echo 'map image for issue uploaded ' . round(filesize($handle5->file_dst_pathname)/256)/4 . 'KB<br /><br />';
                    $gallery_5 = $dir_pics.'/' . $handle5->file_dst_name ;
                } else {
                    echo '  the following error occurred while uploading the map image<br />';
                    echo '  Error: ' . $handle5->error . '<br /><br />';
                }
                $handle5-> Clean();
            }


            $handle6 = new Upload($_FILES['download_1']);
            if ($handle6->uploaded) {
                $handle6->file_max_size = 4000000;
                $handle6->allowed = array('application/*', 'image/*');
                $handle6->Process($dir_dest);
                if ($handle6->processed) {
                    echo 'download one uploaded' . round(filesize($handle6->file_dst_pathname)/256)/4 . 'KB<br /><br />';
                    $download_1 = $dir_pics.'/' . $handle6->file_dst_name ;
                } else {
                    echo '  the following error occurred while uploading download one<br />';
                    echo '  Error: ' . $handle6->error . '<br /><br />';
                }
                $handle6-> Clean();
            }

            $handle7 = new Upload($_FILES['download_2']);
            if ($handle7->uploaded) {
                $handle->file_max_size = 4000000;
                $handle->allowed = array('application/*', 'image/*');
                $handle7->Process($dir_dest);
                if ($handle7->processed) {
                    echo 'download two uploaded' . round(filesize($handle7->file_dst_pathname)/256)/4 . 'KB<br /><br />';
                    $download_2 = $dir_pics.'/' . $handle7->file_dst_name ;
                } else {
                    echo '  the following error occurred while uploading download two<br />';
                    echo '  Error: ' . $handle7->error . '<br /><br />';
                }
                $handle7-> Clean();
            }

            $handle8 = new Upload($_FILES['download_3']);
            if ($handle8->uploaded) {
                $handle->file_max_size = 4000000;
                $handle->allowed = array('application/*', 'image/*');
                $handle8->Process($dir_dest);
                if ($handle8->processed) {
                    echo 'download three uploaded' . round(filesize($handle8->file_dst_pathname)/256)/4 . 'KB<br /><br />';
                    $download_3 = $dir_pics.'/' . $handle8->file_dst_name ;
                } else {
                    echo '  the following error occurred while uploading download three<br />';
                    echo '  Error: ' . $handle8->error . '<br /><br />';
                }
                $handle8-> Clean();
            }



        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO news  (
id,
title = '$title_to_insert' ,
date = '$date_to_insert' ,
trunk = '$trunk_to_insert' ,
introduction = '$introduction_to_insert' ,
title_gallery = '$title_gallery_to_insert' ,
gallery_1 = '$gallery_1_to_insert' ,
gallery_2 = '$gallery_2_to_insert' ,
gallery_3 = '$gallery_3_to_insert' ,
gallery_4 = '$gallery_4_to_insert' , 
gallery_5 = '$gallery_5_to_insert' ,
download_1 = '$download_1_to_insert' ,
download_2 = '$download_2_to_insert' ,
download_3 = '$download_3_to_insert' ,
download_1_title = '$download_1_title_to_insert' ,
download_2_title = '$download_2_title_to_insert' ,
download_3_title = '$download_3_title_to_insert' ,
dropbox_title = '$dropbox_title_to_insert' ,
dropbox_info = '$dropbox_info_to_insert' ,
dropbox_link = '$dropbox_link_to_insert' ,
video_title = '$video_title_to_insert' ,
video = '$video_to_insert'
) VALUES


(NULL,
'$title_to_insert' ,
'$title_gallery_to_insert' ,
'$date_to_insert' ,
'$trunk_to_insert' ,
'$introduction_to_insert',
'$gallery_1_to_insert',
'$gallery_2_to_insert',
'$gallery_3_to_insert',
'$gallery_4_to_insert',
'$gallery_5_to_insert',
'$download_1_to_insert',
'$download_2_to_insert',
'$download_3_to_insert',
'$download_1_title_to_insert',
'$download_2_title_to_insert',
'$download_3_title_to_insert',
'$dropbox_title_to_insert',
'$dropbox_info_to_insert',
'$dropbox_link_to_insert',
'$video_title_to_insert',
'$video_to_insert' );");


if($query) {
            $message = $title . " has been added";


        }else{
            $message = "an error occurred while updating this entry";
            die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());


        }
}



    ?>

    </p>

    <? if(isset($_POST['title'])) { ?>
            <div id="content_holder">
              <p style="text-align:center;padding-top:20px;">
              <strong><? echo $message; ?></strong><br/>
              <span class="error"><? if($error_message) { echo $error_message; } ?></span>
              Add another <a href="add.php">Record/Item</a></p>
            <!-- end content_holder -->
            </div>
       <? }else{ ?>


    <h1 style="padding:10px;">Add News Record</h1>  
     <form action="add_news.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"  name="addResource" id="addResource" method="post" class="cmxform">

    <table cellpadding="10px;" cellspacing="5" width="100%" align="left" valign="top">

    <tr><td colspan="2" align="right"><label>*Required Fields</label></tr>

    <tr>
    <td width="50%">
    <span class="formTitle">General Information</span><br/><br/>
    <label>*Title</label><br/>
    <input id="title" name="title" class="required" />
    </td>
    <td width="50%"><br/><br/>
    <label>*Date</label><br/>
    <input id="date" name="date" class="required"/>
    </td>
    </tr>


        <tr><td colspan="2">
    <label>*Brief News Summary (*200 Characters or Less)</label><br/>
    <p class="smallGrey">Used for list display</p><br/>
    <textarea class="mceNoEditor" id="trunk" name="trunk" style="width: 510px; height: 200px; font-size: 12px;" class="required"/></textarea>
    </td></tr>




    <tr><td colspan="2">
    <label>News Article Content</label><br/>
    <p class="smallGrey">*Basic font styling only for best display</p><br/>
    <textarea style="width: 510px; height: 300px; font-size: 12px; overflow: auto;" id="introduction" name="introduction"></textarea>
    </td></tr>


    <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
    <hr/>
    </td>   
    </tr>




    <tr>
    <td>
    <table width="100%" align="left" valign="top">
    <tr><td><span class="formTitle">Add Gallery Images</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td><p class="smallGrey">*Ideal picture size is 460px by 307px (Landscape). Larger Images will be cropped to these proportions.</p></td></tr>   
    <tr><td><label>Gallery Title/Name</label><br/><input id="title_gallery" name="title_gallery" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label>Image #1</label><br/><input type="file" id="gallery_1" name="gallery_1" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label>Image #2</label><br/><input type="file" id="gallery_2" name="gallery_2" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label>Image #3</label><br/><input type="file" id="gallery_3" name="gallery_3" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label>Image #4</label><br/><input type="file" id="gallery_4" name="gallery_4" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label>Image #5</label><br/><input type="file" id="gallery_5" name="gallery_5" /></td></tr>
    </table>    
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
    <span class="formTitle">Video Embed</span><br/>
    <label>Video Title</label><br/><input id="video_title" name="video_title" /><br/><br/>
    <p class="smallGrey">*Be sure to set the video width to "460" for proper display.</p><br/>
    <label>Video Embed Code</label><br/>
    <textarea class="mceNoEditor" id="video" name="video"/></textarea>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
    <hr/>
    </td>   
    </tr>

    <tr><td>
    <table width="100%" align="left" valign="top">
    <span class="formTitle">Add Downloads</span><br/>
    <tr><td><p class="smallGrey">*5MB Max File Upload Size. Acceptable document types: PDF, Word and Excel</p></td></tr>    
    <tr><td><label>Download Title One</label><br/><input id="download_1_title" name="download_1_title" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label>Download One</label><br/><input type="file" id="download_1" name="download_1" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label>Download Title Two</label><br/><input id="download_2_title" name="download_2_title" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label>Download Two</label><br/><input type="file" id="download_2" name="download_2" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label>Download Title Three</label><br/><input id="download_3_title" name="download_3_title" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label>Download Three</label><br/><input type="file" id="download_3" name="download_3" ></td></tr>
    </table>
    </td>

    <td valign="top">
    <span class="formTitle">Add Dropbox</span><br/>
    <label>Dropbox Title</label><br/>
    <input id="dropbox_title" name="dropbox_title" />
    <br/><br/>
    <label>Dropbox Description</label><br/>
    <input id="dropbox_info" name="dropbox_info" />
    <br/><br/>
    <label>Dropbox Link (No http://)</label><br/>
    <input id="dropbox_link" name="dropbox_link" />

    </td></tr>

    <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
    <hr/>
    </td>   
    </tr>


    <tr><td colspan="2" align="right">
    <p class="smallGrey">*Depending on the number and size of files being uploaded it might take awhile for the browser to process your request. Please only click the submit button once.</p><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Record" class="submit" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="index.php" class="cancel">Cancel</a><br/><br/>

    </td></tr>
        </table>
     </form>
      <?php


    }mysql_close();
    ?>

    </div>



<?php include("../inc/footer.php"); ?>

    <!-- / Container_12 -->
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the actual query that gives that error? if it is in an insert it looks like some of your variables are empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You query is not properly constructed.

It should be something like this :

```
INSERT INTO news (id, title, date, ...) VALUES ($id, '$title', '$date', ...)"
```

But the problem is that you have your values in the part `VALUES (...)` but you also put them for no reason in the first part.

You also should stop using `mysql_*()` as they are deprecated and look [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) to properly construct your queries.

Comment: Specifically, you added the `= XXXX` in the first set of @koopajah's response.